# replace NaN values with the first key value

Tags: javascript, json

I have this object

```
{
  "apple": {
    "0": {
      "2018-04-25 19:51:38": {
        "x": "38.0",
        "y": "23.0"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:39": {
        "x": "NaN",
        "y": "NaN"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:40": {
        "x": "NaN",
        "y": "NaN"
      }
    },
    "5": {
      "2018-04-25 19:51:38": {
        "x": "50.0",
        "y": "35.0"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:39": {
        "x": "50.0",
        "y": "35.0"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:40": {
        "x": "NaN",
        "y": "NaN"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:41": {
        "x": "NaN",
        "y": "NaN"
      },
    },
    "6": {
      "2018-04-25 19:51:34": {
        "x": "30.0",
        "y": "15.0"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:39": {
        "x": "NaN",
        "y": "NaN"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, apple `keys` are not sequentiable number.
Each of these object have different lenght so object with key `0` has lenght 3, the object with key `5` has lenght 4 and the object with key `6` has lenght 2.
Now, I would like that NaN value of key x and y get value of the first timestamp of the same key.
So, what I would like to have is this:

```
{
  "apple": {
    "0": {
      "2018-04-25 19:51:38": {
        "x": "38.0",
        "y": "23.0"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:39": {
        "x": "38.0", // <-- same value of the first element
        "y": "23.0" // <-- same value of the first element
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:40": {
        "x": "38.0", // <-- same value of the first element
        "y": "23.0" // <-- same value of the first element
      }
    },
    "5": {
      "2018-04-25 19:51:38": {
        "x": "50.0",
        "y": "35.0"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:39": {
        "x": "50.0", 
        "y": "35.0" 
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:40": {
        "x": "50.0", // <-- same value of the first element
        "y": "35.0" // <-- same value of the first element
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:41": {
        "x": "50.0", // <-- same value of the first element
        "y": "35.0" // <-- same value of the first element
      },
    },
    "6": {
      "2018-04-25 19:51:34": {
        "x": "30.0",
        "y": "15.0"
      },
      "2018-04-25 19:51:39": {
        "x": "30.0", // <-- same value of the first element
        "y": "15.0" // <-- same value of the first element
      },
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: You will have to loop over the data and fill the gaps. Anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Are `0` `5` and `6` supposed to be arrays?  The ordering of object properties is not guaranteed - you could split out those keys and sort them yourself to get around that though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#forEach` with `Object.keys()` to iterate through each key of your object. Then store the value of `x` and `y` for the first timestamp in a variable and then iterate through each key of your inner object and update the value of all the keys whose value is `NaN`.

```js
let data = { "apple": { "0": { "2018-04-25 19:51:38": { "x": "38.0", "y": "23.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:40": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" } }, "5": { "2018-04-25 19:51:38": { "x": "50.0", "y": "35.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "50.0", "y": "35.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:40": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:41": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, }, "6": { "2018-04-25 19:51:34": { "x": "30.0", "y": "15.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, } } };
Object.keys(data.apple).forEach(k => {
  let x = 'NaN', y = 'NaN';
  Object.keys(data.apple[k]).sort().forEach((k1,i) => {
    if(i === 0) {
      x = data.apple[k][k1].x;
      y = data.apple[k][k1].y;
    } else {
      if(data.apple[k][k1].x === 'NaN')
        data.apple[k][k1].x = x;
      if(data.apple[k][k1].y === 'NaN')
        data.apple[k][k1].y = y;
    }
  });
});
console.log(data);
```

```js
let data = { "apple": { "0": { "2018-04-25 19:51:38": { "x": "38.0", "y": "23.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:40": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" } }, "5": { "2018-04-25 19:51:38": { "x": "50.0", "y": "35.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "50.0", "y": "35.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:40": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:41": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, }, "6": { "2018-04-25 19:51:34": { "x": "30.0", "y": "15.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, } } },
  result = Object.keys(data.apple).reduce((r,k) => {
  let x = 'NaN', y = 'NaN';
  r.apple[k] = {};
  Object.keys(data.apple[k]).sort().forEach((k1,i) => {
    if(i === 0) {
      r.apple[k][k1] = {...data.apple[k][k1]};
      x = data.apple[k][k1].x;
      y = data.apple[k][k1].y;
    } else {
      if(data.apple[k][k1].x === 'NaN')
        r.apple[k][k1] = {x,y};
      if(data.apple[k][k1].y === 'NaN')
        r.apple[k][k1] = {x,y};
    }
  });
  return r;
}, {apple : {}});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Would sort before the foreach be a good addition? `Object.keys(data.apple).sort().forEach(...` might have to override the default sort - js probably can't handle those string dates

Comment: I meant the date keys `2018-04-25 19:51:40` and such - probably works fine just like this +1

Comment: @HassanImam Thanks but is possible to do that in an immutable way? I won't change the original object, I prefer to return a new object..

Comment: @beth Updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Native for is more faster than foreach....
the inmutable way is another question ..must be separated in another question ... however..i attemp to your requiriments...
and whoola..is OK... try the code adobe with ... clone an object (inmutable way)

```js
  
   var hola = {"apple":{"0":{"2018-04-25 19:51:38":{"x":"38.0","y":"23.0"},"2018-04-25 19:51:39":{"x":"NaN","y":"NaN"},"2018-04-25 19:51:40":{"x":"NaN","y":"NaN"}},"5":{"2018-04-25 19:51:38":{"x":"50.0","y":"35.0"},"2018-04-25 19:51:39":{"x":"50.0","y":"35.0"},"2018-04-25 19:51:40":{"x":"NaN","y":"NaN"},"2018-04-25 19:51:41":{"x":"NaN","y":"NaN"}},"6":{"2018-04-25 19:51:34":{"x":"30.0","y":"15.0"},"2018-04-25 19:51:39":{"x":"NaN","y":"NaN"}}}}
    
var original_var = clone(hola);

    for ( property in hola.apple ) {
     
        var property_sub = property 
        property_sub_keys = Object.keys( hola.apple[property_sub] );
        //console.log( property_sub_keys )
    
        for ( var i=0; i<property_sub_keys.length; i++){
          if (i==0) {
              x_ini = hola.apple[property_sub][property_sub_keys[i]].x
              y_ini = hola.apple[property_sub][property_sub_keys[i]].y
          }else{
            if ( hola.apple[property_sub][property_sub_keys[i]].x == "NaN" ){
                hola.apple[property_sub][property_sub_keys[i]].x = x_ini
            }
            if ( hola.apple[property_sub][property_sub_keys[i]].y == "NaN" ){
                hola.apple[property_sub][property_sub_keys[i]].y = y_ini
            }
          }
    
        } 
    
    
    }



function clone(obj) {
    var copy;

    // Handle the 3 simple types, and null or undefined
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;

    // Handle Date
    if (obj instanceof Date) {
        copy = new Date();
        copy.setTime(obj.getTime());
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Array
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        copy = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = obj.length; i < len; i++) {
            copy[i] = clone(obj[i]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    // Handle Object
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
        copy = {};
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = clone(obj[attr]);
        }
        return copy;
    }

    throw new Error("Unable to copy obj! Its type isn't supported.");
}
    console.log(hola)
    console.log(original_var)
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks but is possible to do that in an immutable way? I won't change the original object, I prefer to return a new object..

Comment: the javascript way is no the better way to clone an object...maybe in server side is a best option..however the result expected is done ..check out !

Answer (score 0):

Using `Object.entries()` and `Array#find()` on `Object.values()` to get valid object then `Object.assign()` to update all `NaN`

```js
let data = { "apple": { "0": { "2018-04-25 19:51:38": { "x": "38.0", "y": "23.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:40": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" } }, "5": { "2018-04-25 19:51:38": { "x": "50.0", "y": "35.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "50.0", "y": "35.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:40": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:41": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, }, "6": { "2018-04-25 19:51:34": { "x": "30.0", "y": "15.0" }, "2018-04-25 19:51:39": { "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN" }, } } };


Object.entries(data.apple).forEach(([k,v]) => {
   const valid = Object.values(v).find(({x,y})=> x !=='NaN' && y !=='NaN');
   Object.entries(v).filter(([_,{x,y}])=> x==='NaN' && y==='NaN')
                    .forEach(([k,v])=>Object.assign(v, valid))
   
});
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;}
```

Comment: Thanks but is possible to do that in an immutable way? I won't change the original object, I prefer to return a new object..